# Python selenium rc create_cookie

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't seem to figure out how set cookies with Square brackets [ ] with python for Selenium. This is what i'm trying:

```
selenium.create_cookie("test[country]=nl", "path=/, max_age=6000")
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 55, in test
    sel.create_cookie('test[country]=nl', "path=/, max_age=6000")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\selenium.py", line 1813, in create_cookie
    self.do_command("createCookie", [nameValuePair,optionsString,])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\selenium.py", line 225, in do_command
    raise Exception(data)
Exception: ERROR: Invalid parameter.
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
This is some of the code. It is based on the code exported by IDE.

```
from selenium.selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re
from selenium import webdriver

class country(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://example.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_country_cookie_redirect(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.create_cookie('test[country]=nl', "path=/, max_age=6000")
        sel.open("http://example.com")
        self.assertEqual("http://example.com/nl/nld", sel.get_location()) 

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [add_cookie()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.add_cookie). For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

browser.add_cookie({"name": "test[country]",
                    "value": "nl",
                    "path": "/",
                    "max_age": 6000})

browser.close()
```

UPD (modified test case using webdriver):

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class country(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", {'browserName': 'chrome'})

    def test_country_cookie_redirect(self):
        self.driver.add_cookie({"name": "test[country]",
                                "value": "nl",
                                "path": "/",
                                "max_age": 6000})
        self.driver.get("http://example.com")
        self.assertEqual("http://example.com", self.driver.current_url)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Webdriver is something different than selenium server (RC) right? I need it working with RC.

Comment: @user2511309 well, sure. Correct me if I'm wrong: you have a selenium server and you are using selenium [remote webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver)?

Comment: I'm new to Selenium, so I think I'm mixing things up. I created some scripts with IDE and exported them to Python. They all starts as self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://example.com/"). self.selenium.open("http://exmapele.com") etc. Which is some different than webdriver.get? To use the add_cookie() as you suggested I should rewrite the rest of my exported to 'webdriver' code right?

Comment: @user2511309 ok, start with providing the code you've written so far (update the question). Thanks.